# Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)の「ビルド」で「spresense/.vscode/includeが見つかりません」となる

Tags: spresense

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html

に従い、順に進めていますが、

4.4.1. アプリケーションのビルド

において、

```
"/home/user/spresense/.vscode/include"が見つかりません
```

となります。ターミナルウィンドウで最初のエラーを見ると

```
make[3]: ディレクトリ '/home/user/spresense/sdk/apps/nshlib' に入ります
sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
ERROR: arm-none-eabi-gcc failed: 127
       command: arm-none-eabi-gcc -M -fno-builtin -mabi=aapcs -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow -Wundef -g -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-strength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -I. -isystem /home/user/spresense/nuttx/include -isystem /home/user/spresense/nuttx/../sdk/include -D__KERNEL__ -pipe -gdwarf-3 -I /home/user/spresense/sdk/apps/include ./nsh_init.c
make[3]: *** [/home/user/spresense/sdk/apps/Application.mk:209: .depend] エラー 1
```

となっています。lsで確認すると、確かにincludeディレクトリは存在しません。

```
$ ls ~/spresense/.vscode/
application.mk  build.sh  c_cpp_properties.json  clean_flash.sh  launch.json  spresense_prj.json  tasks.json  worker.mk
```

SDKのインストールに失敗しているのでしょうか？

環境：
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
VS Code Ver. 1.56.1 (本日時点の最新バージョン)
SDK Ver. 2.1.0 (本日時点の最新バージョン)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最初のエラーを見ると、ARM GCCコンパイラへのパスが通っていないようですね。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_linux%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97

こちらの、
「このコマンドは、ターミナルを開くごとに実行する必要があります。このコマンドを省略したい場合は、ホームディレクトリ以下の .bashrc に上記コマンドを追加してください。」
という記載に従って、
.bashrcへの追記はされているでしょうか。
していなければ、追記してみてください。

Comment: .bashrcに追加したところ、ビルドは成功しました。
しかしながら「"/home/user/spresense/.vscode/include"が見つかりません」
は出続けています。これは無視しても良いのでしょうか？

Comment: よく見たら、IntelliSenseがらみのエラーのようだったので、ディレクトリがありさえすれば良いのかと思い、mkdir ~/spresense/.vscode/includeしてみたところ、エラーが消えました。

Answer (score 0):

`arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found`
とログ上見受けられますが、 `install-tools.sh` を使用して環境をセットアップしていますか？
インストールしているとすればPATHが通っていないようですね。

[2.1.1. Linux向けセットアップ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_linux%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)